# how to customise notifications/popup for leaves in odoo 11.0

Tags: notifications, odoo-11

how to get/send notification to user (HR Manager) if an employees applies for leave in systray where we have chat notifications and activity notifications. 
i have uploaded image [Please check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnzQG.png)